# Daterangepicker disable the 2nd calendar and use it as a datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, daterangepicker

I have this example

```
    $('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
            timePicker: true,
            startDate: new Date(),
            endDate: new Date(),
            locale: {
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
            }

        }, function(start, end, label) {
            $("#range1").val(start.format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:00')+" - "+end.format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:00'));
    });
```

How I can change dynamically a daterangepicker into a datepicker?

Comment: you want to disable the timepicker so that it will only select dates, then you can set `timePicker: false,` is that what you want???

Comment: @nivas more or less, the daterangepicker generate 2 calendars and I want convert to a datepicker and when I click in a button it just generate 1 calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Just add: "singleDatePicker: true" to your code:

```
 $('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        timePicker: true,
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: new Date(),
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
        }

    }, function(start, end, label) {
        $("#range1").val(start.format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:00')+" - "+end.format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:00'));
});
```

Documentation: http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example3

You can test all the variables here: http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config

Answer (score 0):

remove the time fields from the code like this

```
$('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
            timePicker: true,
            startDate: new Date(),
            endDate: new Date(),
            locale: {
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
            }

        }, function(start, end, label) {
            $("#range1").val(start.format('MM/DD/YYYY')+" - "+end.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
    });
```

hope it will work for you